When printing a list with colored items it prints the color code
As said in the title I'm trying to print a list that contains a colored number.
The code
from termcolor import colored
lista = [1,5,12,54,63,colored(23,"red"),65]
print(lista)

The terminal
[1, 5, 12, 54, 63, '\x1b[31m23\x1b[0m', 65]

I was expecting to see 23 in a red color but it printed the code

The function colored() packs the number (23 here) in an ANSI escape sequence that would show the number in colours, when printed in a  e.g. terminal. However, this ANSI-sequence is a string, and that is, what you see here. Try for i in lista: print (i) to get the output and run it in a terminal that is capable of interpreting ANSI escape sequences to see the  colours. Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-do-i-print-colored-text-to-the-terminal/287944#287944

Or print("["+",".join(map(str, lista))+"]")

When you print a list, it prints the repr() of the list elements, not str().

The issue you're encountering is that when you print the list containing the colored number, the escape codes for the color formatting are also included in the output. Terminal escape codes are not interpreted by print() directly. Instead, they are used by the terminal to format text.
To achieve the desired output, you should individually print each element of the list rather than printing the list as a whole. This way, the color formatting will be applied correctly. Here's how you can do it:

from termcolor import colored

lista = [1, 5, 12, 54, 63, colored(23, "red"), 65]

for item in lista:
    print(item, end=" ")

or you can unpack those list items:

from termcolor import colored

lista = [1, 5, 12, 54, 63, colored(23, "red"), 65]

print(*lista, sep=" ")

